# Is Azure ARM Template deployment transactional?

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager

Lets say I'm deploying an Azure VM by scripting which requires multiple resources interdependent on one another.

Lets say a NIC fails,

1. Does the deployment script still go through to the deployment of the VM? So that I have a VM with no NIC
2. Does it fail rolling back the entire script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ARM templates are not executed within a transaction.

1. It's possible that you have deployed resources without deploying the whole ARM template. In your case it's not possible to have a VM without a NIC (But you test the deployment of the ARM template and make it work at the end.)
2. It does not roll back.

Comment: It's indeed not possible to have a VM without a NIC. It is possible to have resources without deploying the whole ARM template because it fails. Changed my answer

Comment: So you mean that if a part of an ARM template for a NIC fails at runtime (not validation inside Visual Studio) then the ARM script for provisioning a VM does not even run just because it [dependsOn] the NIC

If it does not roll back then I can have a virtual network, subnet, but no NIC and VM. Is that right?

@4c74356b41 Can you please shed some light on the above?

Comment: yes, if something fails, everything that depends on it won't get deployed at all @HamzaAhmedZia and yes, everything else will be in place (subnet, vnet, network security group, etc)

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

I think now they have added "--rollback-on-error" flag to rollback on last successful deployment if the deployment fails. Also you can specify the name of the deployment to which you need to roll back refer this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#commands.